# Xamarin.Forms .193 - AppCompat - Full screen - no action bar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting a full screen (no title bar/statusbar/navbar) when your MainActivity is inheriting from FormsApplicationActivity isn't much of a problem.
But then you can't theme it etc.

The current VS solution templates have you inheriting from `FormsAppCompatActivity` which you can theme.  But then the status bar comes back.
It just shouldn't be days of looking at out-of-date how-to pages and mountains of trial and error with countless permutations of these different 'tricks' just to get a full-page app.  I have hit every google search, every stack overflow, other questions here with examples that once worked in 2011 and so on.  But I can't find or figure out how to make it work today, 2017 on a modern VS solution.

Maybe I've just tried so many different ways I've gotten lost or have multiple different ways conflicting with each other, but can anyone show me how on a basic "Welcome To Xamarin" kind of app how to get it go full screen?  I've gotten so close, but not quite there.  The best I can do is to have no content *in* the status bar, but the bar itself is still there.  I can' t believe something as common place as wanting a full-screen app is kicking my arse, but it is.
[image]

### Get rid of the Navigation bar

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RpxOne.MainPage());

    }
```

### MainActivity.cs

Set the theme in the `Activity` attributes
Set the windows flags
(Clearly lot of various efforts and permutations to get this to work)

```
[Activity(Label = "RpxOne",
          Icon = "@drawable/icon",
          Theme = "@style/FullScreen",
          MainLauncher = true,
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize |
                                 ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    WindowManagerFlags _originalFlags;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        SupportRequestWindowFeature((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        //RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        //if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        //{
        //    // Kill status bar underlay added by FormsAppCompatActivity
        //    // Must be done before calling FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate

        //    this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;
        //    ActionBar?.Hide();
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        //    SupportActionBar?.Hide();
        //}

        //global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
        //Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);
        //Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        //Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen |
        //                WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn |
        //                WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);

        this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); // hide the status bar
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
```

### And then the theme itself

```
  <style name="FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>-->

    <!--<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

    --><!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float --><!--
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>


    --><!--<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>-->
  </style>
```

Original post on Xamarin Forums
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90145/how-to-get-a-full-screen-app-in-todays-xf-193-appcompat-environment-it-shouldnt-be-this-hard
No replies - I can't believe this is such a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Code for hiding title bar and action bar actually works, the action bar you see is a view created by Xamarin.Forms view renderer. By checking the [Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-walkthru.html) of DDMS, you can see this view:

[image]

Since we cannot modify the source code of xamarin forms, here is a workaround to solve this issue. Create a style like so:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

  <!--colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar-->
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#fff9f9f9</item>
</style>
```

And in `MainActivity`:

```
[Activity(Label = "FormsIssue6", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        //RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        //Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

This is only a workaround, the view there for action bar will still occupy the space in the layout.

And the reason why I used color `#fff9f9f9`, I only check the [souce code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml), the `<drawable name="input_method_fullscreen_background">` item seems to be right by my side, I didn't find the source code for Xamarin.Forms, you can give a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - especially at such an early hour (at least in my time zone)

> This is only a workaround, the view there for action bar will still occupy the space in the layout.<

That's the heart of the issue I'm trying to resolve.  In my 'real' project I colored the bar black making it disappear/blend with the black bezel of the device the company selected. I also killed off the pull-down behavior that opens the notifications control etc. The ViewRenderer reference is a great tip-Maybe I can do something with a CustomRenderer. I'll keep the thread aware if successful.

Comment: @ClintStLaurent, you're welcome, and I doubt that can be customized. Checked the source code of [FormsAppCompatActivity](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/FormsAppCompatActivity.cs), it will always create a `_statusBarUnderlay` in code behind. This is why I give that word around.